# Apache not running on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

So initially I was getting an error on WAMP :

The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 0; [EParseError] No tray icon was specified. Please assign a tray icon by using on the of the Trayicon directoives in the [Config] section.

So I found a solution on stack overflow which said :

Go to the wamp/scripts folder

Open console

run: php refresh.php

So I ran this and the error is gone. But now only 2 services are running out of 3.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh2iq.jpg)

As you can see in image. I have tried starting wampapache64 but it keeps on stopping.
How can I fix this. I am doing a  project so I don't want to loose my databases by reinstalling WAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I didn't know how to fix that the error but keeping a backup of mysql folder in bin and then replacing the mysql folder after fresh installation of WAMP worked. Make sure you also make a backup of www folder.
The problem was with this file :
wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf\httpd.conf
Re-installing fixed that.